# Заполнение ListBox в новом потоке

Tags: wpf, многопоточность, асинхронность, task

Всем доброго времени суток!

Цель: получив список участников беседы Вконтакте, пытаюсь в новом потоке вывести с помощью их уникального идентификатора Фамилию и Имя в `listbox`.

Синхронно всё получается, но сами знаете что при этом программа засыпает на пару секунд. Сначала необходимо чтобы форма инициализировалась, была на экране, а потом уже идет запуск `task.Start();` ...но увы ничего в список не выводит.

Вот метод, и запуск метода в асинхронном потоке:

```
private void GetUsersOnGroup()
        {
            // Получить Id всех участников беседы
            var users = api.Messages.GetChatUsers(chatId);
            // Максимальное значение - это кол-во элементов в коллекции
            pb_Process.Maximum = users.Count;
            foreach (var userId in users)
            {
                // Добавить в ListBox новую "Фамилия И." участника беседы
                lb_Users.Items.Add(api.Users.Get(userId).LastName 
                                   + " " + api.Users.Get(userId).FirstName[0] + ".");
                pb_Process.Value++; // Увеличить значение прогресс бара на 1
            }
        }
```

Следующая часть кода записывается в конец конструктора главной формы:

```
Task task = new Task(GetUsersOnGroup);
task.Start();
```

Comment: Для меня многопоточность весьма больная тема. Очень сильно нуждаюсь в советах.

Comment: Балуясь, сделал метод асинхронным async, и делал паузу в 50 миллисекунд перед добавлением строки в  listbox с помощью 
await Task.Delay(50);

Comment: я использую wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем народ, я ошибся, не договорив, что коллекцию я брал из сервера vk.com, и искал пользователей по id тоже не локально :)
Я понял, что нужен некий timeout, выделенный каждому запросу,

`ask.Delay(150);` // Выделив 150 миллисекунд на каждый запрос поиска ФИО по айди я смело заполнил список в новом потоке. И всё же, если есть способ лучше - напишите в сюда в комменты. ***Спасибо большое заранее.***